# Lint Detector Does Not Detect Class Usages From Jar Files

Tags: android, android-lint

Given the following application structures:

**Structure A:**

```
-- App Root
    |
    |
    -- Android Module (class detector detects and usage in here)
    |
    |
    -- Custom Lint Module (detector defined here)
```

**Structure B:**

```
-- App Root
    |
    |
    -- Android Module (class usage in here)
    |
    |
    -- Jar Module (class detector detects in here)
    |
    |
    -- Custom Lint Module (detector defined here)
```

**Structure A** *detects* usages of some class X defined and used in the Android Module.

**Structure B** *fails to detect* usages of class X defined in the Jar Module and used in the Android Module.

Simply moving my class X to a Jar Module breaks lint detection. My detector is a modified version of [this one](https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber/blob/master/timber-lint/src/main/java/timber/lint/WrongTimberUsageDetector.java) from Jake Wharton.